# Get List Of Class's Attributes Including Attributes Of Sub Objects - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I want to get a list of all the attributes of the class including the attributes used in sub_objects of this class.

Example:

```
@dataclass
class Phones:
    mobile: Optional[str] = None
    work_phone: Optional[str] = None

@dataclass
class People:
    id: str
    name: str
    phones: Phones
```

I have People class and one of its attributes is of type `Phones`.
I want to return this list:

```
['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'work_phone']
```

I tried `__dict__`, `__annotations__`, `dir()` and more staff but I can't find a way to do it generic and dynamic. My solution is to do a convertor and return this list hardcoded which seems as a bad idea for maintenance.

I want all the attributes with primitive type. (For example I don't want to include `phones`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/13526701/noblockhit

I managed to achieve what I wanted with the next code:

```
def list_attributes(entity: object) -> List[str]:
    """
    @returns: List of all the primitive attributes
    """
    attributes: List[str] = []
    entity_attributes = entity.__annotations__.items()
    for attribute_name, attribute_type in entity_attributes:
        if is_dataclass(attribute_type):
            attributes += list_attributes(attribute_type)
        else:
            attributes.append(attribute_name)
    return attributes
```

Comment: The else is important to not include 'phones'

Answer (score 0):

Recursion?
You dont need the sbNative thing, its just my module for clean logging.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass
from typing import Optional
from sbNative.debugtools import log

@dataclass
class Phones:
    mobile: Optional[str] = None
    work_phone: Optional[str] = None

@dataclass
class People:
    id: str
    name: str
    phones: Phones
    

def find_dataclasses(cls):
    classes = []
    for obj in cls.__annotations__.values():
        if is_dataclass(obj):
            classes += find_dataclasses(obj)
        classes.append(obj)
    return classes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log(*find_dataclasses(People))
```

Answer (score 0):

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73486501/10237506) is good, but unfortunately it won't work if you have a more complex annotation, such as a container type like `List[Phones]`. For example:

```
@dataclass
class Phones:
    mobile: Optional[str] = None
    work_phone: Optional[str] = None

@dataclass
class People:
    id: str
    name: str
    phones: List[Phones]
```

The current output will be: `['id', 'name', 'phones']`. But, note that we want to exclude the field `phones`, and include all the fields of the Phone class, `mobile` and `work_phone`.

To handle such types, you can use `typing.get_args()` and iterate over each of the subscripted types, checking if each type is a dataclass.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass
from typing import Optional, List, get_args


@dataclass
class Phones:
    mobile: Optional[str] = None
    work_phone: Optional[str] = None


@dataclass
class People:
    id: str
    name: str
    phones: List[Phones]


def list_attributes(entity: object) -> List[str]:
    """
    @returns: List of all the primitive attributes
    """
    attributes: List[str] = []
    entity_attributes = entity.__annotations__.items()
    for attribute_name, attribute_type in entity_attributes:
        args = get_args(attribute_type)

        if args:
            found_class = False
            for arg in args:
                if is_dataclass(arg):
                    found_class = True
                    attributes += list_attributes(arg)
            if not found_class:
                attributes.append(attribute_name)
        elif is_dataclass(attribute_type):
            attributes += list_attributes(attribute_type)
        else:
            attributes.append(attribute_name)

    return attributes


print(list_attributes(People))
```

The above modified version correctly outputs the desired result:

```
['id', 'name', 'mobile', 'work_phone']
```